# Использовать картинки из обозревателя решений

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

подскажите как можно фото из обозревателя решений вставить через код, все скрины скинул. Само фото в обозревателе ршений находится в папке. Код ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```cs
public Test()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GameList.ItemsSource = games;
}

List<Game> games = new List<Game>
{
    new Game { Name = "Тест", Image = "dl2.jpeg" },
    new Game { Name = "Тест", Image = "1.jpg" },
};
```

```xml
<Grid>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public class Game
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Начнем с того, что нет такого понятия, как "из обозревателя решений". Есть либо ресурсы, либо файлы на диске, настраивается это в свойствах, которые выскакивают если нажать на изображение. Если изображение добавлено как ресурс, то обращаться к нему надо примерно так: `/НазваниеСборки;component/путь/до/изображения.png`. Также, если проект .NET, то он может быть нацелен на кроссплатформенность, то есть нацелен на разные OS, и чтоб WPF понял, что работа идет с путями Windows, то `TargetFramework` должен быть указан с припиской `-windows`.